# Prevent window rearrangement every time I open mission control

Tags: mission-control

I found mission control quite awkward. The problem is I have four IntelliJ open under one space and I need to switch between them without pain. Every time I open mission control these windows are in a different location. I need to hover over each IntelliJ window to find the proper project. Eye memory is helpless because they are in different locations every time. I also tried to group the same application windows but still, productivity has not increased. They are hiding each other is quite hard to point out the proper project. I don't want to open each project in a separate space because it's an additional headache to slide between windows every time you need a small change. In my understanding, unchecking the first option should stop this kind of behaviour. Otherwise what else does the first option do?
So is it possible to somehow pin window position in mission control? or what is the other efficient approach? Any suggestion would be helpful

First option
[image]

Second Option:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need Mission Control when all your IntelliJ projects are open in the same space/desktop anyway? Doesn't IntelliJ have a shortcut to switch between projects?

Comment: maybe a screenshot of your 'before' & 'after' scenarios? I'm having difficulty visualising exactly what you mean. And, as @nohillside says, Spaces is not relevant to this if everything is inside a single Space. Do you use multiple displays?

Comment: @nohillside there is command + ` shortcut to iterate through the same application windows, but this is not exactly what I need.

Comment: So your problem is rather that Mission Control doesn't use a consistent ordering when showing the windows open in a space/desktop?

Comment: @nohillside something like this. To be more clear my problem is that windows don't remain in the same location where I left them. I just can't simply open mission control assuming that the window is still there where I left it. Every time I open mission control need to struggle my eyes by looking over the screen(scan the whole screen) to find the desired window.

Comment: is this what you mean - that the spread of grouped windows is different each time - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQSq.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QKVy.png? That's based on last access & I doubt you can change the behaviour. Does IntelliJ have a Window menu? That would seem the most certain way to bring the correct one to the front.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes IntelliJ has window menu and it work fine but I need application windows that are open for that particular desktop and it shows all of them(I mean from different space or desktop)

Comment: Sorry, each time you add more information I get more confused. I asked about Spaces earlier & this is the first time you've mentioned them. I now really have no idea quite what is happening. The only thing I can guess is when you refer to Mission Control, you actually mean 'Application window's, which *does* gather app windows from all Spaces. Mission Control doesn't.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for the confusion. The only thing is I need is somehow have static(fixed) locations for the applications window in mission control. Every time I open mission control(I mean the same space) the application is arranged automatically.